# Add previous row data to dynamically generated row for storing data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I copy this part of code for adding rows dynamically and it works very well:

```
<script>
//define template
var template = $('#sections .section:first').clone();
//define counter
var sectionsCount = 1;
//add new section
$('body').on('click', '.addsection', function() {
    //increment
    sectionsCount++;
    //loop through each input
    var section = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){
        //set id to store the updated section number
        var newId = this.id + sectionsCount;
        //update for label
        $(this).prev().attr('for', newId);
        //update id - THIS CAUSES JqueryUI Datepicker to bug, also you shouldn't use numerical only IDs
        //this.id = newId;
    }).end()
    //inject new section
    .appendTo('#sections');
    //initialize datePicker on last name=date[] element in HTML DOM
    $("input[name='date[]']").last().datepicker();
    return false;
});
//init original datePicker in HTML DOM
$("input[name='date[]']").last().datepicker();
//remove section
$('#sections').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    //fade out section
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
        //remove parent element (main section)
        $(this).parent().parent().empty();
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});

</script>
```

Can you modify this script to add previous row data to dynamically generated row
now the script only create new row with empty field like in this screenshot:

[image]

Can you help me to solve this problem?

I use codeigniter framework.

Thanks a lot, riccardo

Answer (score 0):

You're copying/cloning a variable called `template` which is defined at the top as the first section. You can assign value to it at the time of adding section and it could be the last section.

```
let sectionsCount = 1;
$('body').on('click', '.addsection', function() {
   const template = $('#sections .section:last').clone();
   sectionsCount++;

   //loop through each input
   template.find('input').each(function(){
     //set id to store the updated section number
     const newId = this.id + sectionsCount;
     //update for label
     $(this).prev().attr('for', newId);
     //update id - THIS CAUSES JqueryUI Datepicker to bug, also you shouldn't use numerical only IDs
     //this.id = newId;
   });

   //inject new section
   template.appendTo('#sections');

   //initialize datePicker on last name=date[] element in HTML DOM
   $("input[name='date[]']").last().datepicker(); 
});
```

PS - I haven't tested it.

Comment: can you rewrite me if you can the entire script ? i have insert in my sript but its doesnt work

Comment: Create a jsfiddle or similar

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for testing ?